# How to change the resolution?

Tags: splinter-cell-blacklist

I have started playing this game and I noticed that the default resolution is 1280x800 (16:10).

My monitor is 1920x1200, and I would like to run the game at that resolution, but the highest available resolution in the game options is 1600x1200 (16:10) which looks incredibly bad.

Does anyone know how I can enable the options to allow the game to run at my monitors native resolution?

Comment: I have rolled back the edit on this question, as the ingame options display is 1600x1200 at 16:10, which then stretches the screen to fit. It's not an error :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that running in 'Fullscreen' mode doens't allow actual fullscreen resolution, once I changed my display setting to 'Borderless' it automatically switched to my monitors native resolution.